# Access same boolean from different scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine

my unity project build from 3 scenes, it can start from any scene.
each scene have a `GameObject` that hold a script called `isFirstSceneLoaded` as the script called all it have to do is to check if that scene is the first to be loaded from the game.so lets say i have a `bool` called `isFirstScene` and its initially set to no, but when the script first `Start()` gets called i am setting it to true.
so now when i will switch scene this bool will be equals to true.

how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a static class

```
public static class FirstSceneLoaded
{
    private static bool isFirstScene = false;

    public static void setBool(String sceneName)
    {
        if(sceneName == "first")
          isFirstScene = true;
    }
}
```

Since the class is static there will only be one instance of it and it will exist through the whole execution of the game.

Call it like this

```
 void Start()
 {
     FirstSceneLoaded.setBool(Application.loadedLevelName);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in two ways 
1) make empty object place script in it that has the bool in it and just don't destroy it on the load ..
2) you can create script with class IsSceneLoaded delete the inheritance from mono behavior and make static function (don't forget to delete Update and start functions)

```
 public static bool GetBool() {// declare static bool in the class let's say its name 
DidLoad return DidLoad; }
```

//if you want a function to set it

public static void SetBool(bool newval)
    {DidLoad=newval;
    }

either ways should work fine if it doesn't comment on my answer if you don't want to add game objects just use the second one :P

Comment: You could also save the value in a PlayerPref

Comment: Yeah that probably would be better 